# How do I set the below cluster spark coonfiguration property

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I see below snippets from Databricks docs. but I dont find anywhere how to do this step. Can someone guide me. Also if someone can confirm, that By enabling this property, users will not be able to see the cluster logs

> Secrets are not redacted from the Spark driver log streams stdout and
> stderr. To protect secrets that might appear in those driver log
> streams such that only users with the Can Manage permission on the
> cluster can view them, set the cluster’s Spark configuration property
> spark.databricks.acl.needAdminPermissionToViewLogs true. You have Can
> Manage permission for any cluster that you create.

Screen shot of cluster:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure your cluster for the requested permissions you can follow the below steps:

1. Open the Databricks workspace.
2. Go to the Clusters page
3. In the "**Spark Config**" section, add a new key-value pair with the following details:

   ```
   Key: spark.databricks.acl.needAdminPermissionToViewLogs
   Value: true ![enter image description here]()
   ```

   [image]
4. Once you have entered the Key and Value, confirm and restart the
   cluster.

Here is more information about [Cluster access control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/auth-authz/access-control/cluster-acl)

***Note*:** ***Enabling the spark.databricks.acl.needAdminPermissionToViewLogs property with a value of true does restrict the visibility of cluster logs to users who have the "Can Manage" permission on the cluster.
Other users without the necessary permissions will not be able to see the cluster logs.***

You can refer this [Configure cluster-level permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/auth-authz/access-control/cluster-acl#configure-cluster-level-permissions)
[image]

Comment: I am the admin of the databricks workspace and have can manage permission to the cluster but the above setting you show is disabled for me. I can see one key in there "spark.databricks.delta.preview.enabled true" But I dont have option to add anything there

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Can you share some screen shots of the cluster page?

Comment: added the picture now

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint Are you able to do the edit? the cluster page?

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint At the top right corner you see the edit Button. Just try using it.